# How to show content from second Cell in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

i want to make Swift app with CollectionView in Xcode, i have implemented it well and now i want to show some other stuff after some Posts, and i have created Xib and swift file for it. but the problem is when i try to show label in new cell i got this error ,,

[image]

i have registered new cell in ViewDidLoad Like this:

```
 collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    collectionView.register(AdViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "adCell")
```

and i have used 300X250 space in AdViewCell and when i load posts i can see the white space of 300X250 size.. look at this

[image]

but even when i try to change its background color or anything , nothing happens when app is loaded..

i have connected Label to AdViewCell also..

```
class AdViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var namelbl: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}
```

please help

Comment: Your are using "cell" and "adcell" for the same indexPath.

Comment: @Klinki how ? can you please explain ?

Comment: It seems `namelbl` is not connected properly. Double check it.

Comment: @burnsi i have checked it and its connected properly

Comment: [Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines. Images should only be used as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Your are using "cell" and "adcell" for the same indexPath.

try this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
    if indexPath.item % 5 == 1 {

        let adcell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "adcell", for: indexPath) as! AdViewCell

        return adcell
    }else{

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MovieCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MovieCollectionViewCell

        return cell 
    }
}
```

Comment: still the same error "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" @Klinki

Comment: @noorapps which object does the message says is nil when it gets unwrapped?

Comment: the Label which is in AdViewCell Xib file,,

Answer (score 0):

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

```
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() //optional, to get from any UIButton for example

let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell

print(currentCell.textLabel!.text)
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code.